# modify the html tag in table using Jquery , CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the html code as below:

```
<table class="table_inscription">

    <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label class="social fb"><p class="nonetext">Facebook</p></label> <input class="text social" type="text" name="facebook" value="<?=$facebook;?>" /></td>
            <td colspan="2"><label class="social socialright sk"><p class="nonetext">SoundClick</p></label> <input class="text social" type="text" name="soundclick" value="<?=$soundclick;?>" /></td>                              
        </tr>   

</table>
```

And I want to change it to :

```
<table class="table_inscription">

    <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label class="social fb"><p class="nonetext">Facebook</p></label> <input class="text social" type="text" name="facebook" value="<?=$facebook;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label class="social socialright sk"><p class="nonetext">SoundClick</p></label> <input class="text social" type="text" name="soundclick" value="<?=$soundclick;?>" /></td>                              
    </tr>   

</table>
```

By using CSS JQUERY and other method ,someone know please help me please, Thanks

Comment: and what is the change here??

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unwrap` and `wrap`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/KAFMN/)**

```
$(function(){
   $('td').unwrap('<tr>');
   $('td').wrap('<tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just did something very similar to this tonight. I ended up simply rebuilding the table:

```
var $newTableEntity = $('<table />');

$('.table_inscription td').each( function(index, td_element){
    var $newRow = $('<tr />').append( td_element );
    $newTableEntity.append( $newRow );
});

$('.table_inscription').replaceWith( $newTableEntity );
```

Note that this is using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var $table = $('table').clone();
$table.html('');
$('td').each(function () {
    var $tr = $('<tr/>').html($(this).clone());
    $table.append($tr);
});
$('table').remove();
$table.appendTo('body');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5nsN/)

Read [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) and [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap)

Or simply,

```
$('td').unwrap('<tr>');
$('td').wrap('<tr>');
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/d5nsN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
var table = $(".table_inscription");
var tds = table.find("td");
table.empty();
for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    table.append($('<tr><td>' + tds.eq(i).html() + '</td></tr>'));
}
```

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VSF38/

Answer (score 0):

do some thing like

```
var val = $('.table_inscription').html();

val = val.replace("<tr>","");
val = val.replace("</tr>","");
val = val.replace("<td","<tr><td");
val = val.replace("</td>","</td></tr>");

$('.table_inscription').html("");
$('.table_inscription').html(val);
```

Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery. this way, Put below code at bottom or after head tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('td').unwrap('<tr>');
        $('td').wrap('<tr>');
    });
  </script>
```